# error: operator '&&' has no right operand

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, compiler-errors, arduino

I followed the guide to import the Ardupilot project in eclipse (https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/wiki/Eclipse)

The first time I could build the project but after that I always get these two errors:

```
autogenerated:1:33: error: operator '&&' has no right operand
```

[...]

```
make: *** [/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.o] Error 1
```

more in dettail:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project ArduPilot-mega ****

make apm1 
make: ../sketchbook/Tools/scripts/arduino_version.sh: Command not found
../mk//Arduino.mk:537: warning: overriding recipe for target `clean'
../libraries/AP_Common/Arduino.mk:324: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `clean'
../mk//Arduino.mk:555: warning: overriding recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.elf'
../libraries/AP_Common/Arduino.mk:341: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.elf'
../mk//Arduino.mk:560: warning: overriding recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.hex'
../libraries/AP_Common/Arduino.mk:346: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.hex'
../mk//Arduino.mk:565: warning: overriding recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.eep'
../libraries/AP_Common/Arduino.mk:351: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.eep'
../mk//Arduino.mk:642: warning: overriding recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/arduino/core.a'
../libraries/AP_Common/Arduino.mk:428: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/arduino/core.a'
../mk//Arduino.mk:663: warning: overriding recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.cpp'
../libraries/AP_Common/Arduino.mk:449: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.cpp'
../mk/targets.mk:65: warning: overriding recipe for target `etags'
%% ArduPilotMega.o
../mk//targets.mk:65: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `etags'
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.h:7:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:30:
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_SIRF.h:26:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_SIRF.h:64:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.h:9:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:30:
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_UBLOX.h:28:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_UBLOX.h:77:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.h:10:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:30:
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_MTK.h:28:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_MTK.h:39:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.h:11:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:30:
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_MTK16.h:27:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_MTK16.h:41:0: warning: ignoring #pragma pack 
autogenerated:1:33: error: operator '&&' has no right operand
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS.h:15:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:30:
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_Shim.h: In member function 'virtual bool AP_GPS_Shim::read()':
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_GPS/AP_GPS_Shim.h:24:8: warning: unused variable 'updated'
In file included from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:39:0:
../sketchbook/libraries/PID/PID.h: In member function 'void PID::operator()(float, float, float, int16_t)':
../sketchbook/libraries/PID/PID.h:107:39: warning: declaration of 'imax' shadows a member of 'this'
In file included from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:44:0:
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h: In function 'void comm_send_ch(mavlink_channel_t, uint8_t)':
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:28:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_2' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:28:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_3' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:28:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_NB' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:28:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_NB_HIGH' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h: In function 'uint8_t comm_receive_ch(mavlink_channel_t)':
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:47:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_2' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:47:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_3' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:47:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_NB' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:47:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_NB_HIGH' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h: In function 'uint16_t comm_get_available(mavlink_channel_t)':
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:65:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_2' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:65:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_3' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:65:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_NB' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_MAVLink.h:65:11: warning: enumeration value 'MAVLINK_COMM_NB_HIGH' not handled in switch
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde: In function 'void __vector_25()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:63:1: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde: In function 'void __vector_36()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:64:1: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde: In function 'void __vector_54()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:65:1: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Attitude.pde: In function 'void stabilize()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Attitude.pde:9:14: warning: unused variable 'temp'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/GCS_Mavlink.pde: In member function 'void GCS_MAVLINK::handleMessage(mavlink_message_t*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/GCS_Mavlink.pde:469:21: warning: unused variable 'type'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/GCS_Mavlink.pde:564:21: warning: unused variable 'loadAction'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'int8_t help_log(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:30:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'int8_t erase_logs(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:136:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'int8_t select_logs(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:157:21: warning: operation on 'bits' may be undefined
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'int8_t process_logs(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:185:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'void start_new_log(byte)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:225:6: warning: unused variable 'page'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:228:7: warning: unused variable 'data'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'void get_log_boundaries(byte, byte, int&, int&)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:283:11: warning: declaration of 'byte num_logs' shadows a parameter
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:260:30: warning: shadowed declaration is here
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'int find_last_log_page(int)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:312:15: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde: In function 'void add_altitude_data(long unsigned int, long int)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde:21:16: warning: unused variable 'i'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde:22:6: warning: unused variable 'dx'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/commands_process.pde: In function 'void change_command(uint8_t)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/commands_process.pde:5:34: warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde:7:15: warning: shadowed declaration is here
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/planner.pde: In function 'int8_t planner_mode(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/planner.pde:23:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/planner.pde: In function 'int8_t planner_gcs(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/planner.pde:47:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/radio.pde: In function 'void throttle_failsafe(uint16_t)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/radio.pde:116:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_mode(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:44:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_show(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:51:11: warning: unused variable 'i'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_factory(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:77:11: warning: unused variable 'i'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_flightmodes(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:188:23: warning: declaration of 'oldSwitchPosition' shadows a global declaration
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:180:9: warning: shadowed declaration is here
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_declination(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:270:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_erase(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:276:11: warning: unused variable 'i'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde: In function 'int8_t setup_compass(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/setup.pde:296:8: warning: unused variable 'junkbool'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/system.pde: In function 'void init_ardupilot()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/system.pde:143:8: warning: unused variable 'junkbool'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/system.pde:48:6: warning: unused variable 'last_log_start'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/system.pde:49:6: warning: unused variable 'last_log_end'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/system.pde: In function 'void startup_IMU_ground()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/system.pde:433:11: warning: unused variable 'store'
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/test.pde: In function 'int8_t test_mode(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/test.pde:72:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/test.pde: In function 'void test_wp_print(Location*, byte)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/test.pde:319:47: warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde:7:15: warning: shadowed declaration is here
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Common.h:37:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/BetterStream.h:16,
                 from ../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/FastSerial.h:56,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:27:
../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Var.h: In constructor 'AP_VarT<T>::AP_VarT(AP_Var_group*, AP_Var::Key, T, const prog_char_t*, AP_Var::Flags) [with T = float, AP_Var::Key = unsigned int, AP_Var::Flags = unsigned char]':
../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Var.h:870:63:   instantiated from here
../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Var.h:514:5: warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde:7:15: warning: shadowed declaration is here
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_Compass/../AP_Math/AP_Math.h:6:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_Compass/AP_Compass_HMC5843.h:5,
                 from ../sketchbook/libraries/AP_Compass/AP_Compass.h:6,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:35:
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_Compass/../AP_Math/vector3.h: In constructor 'Vector3<T>::Vector3() [with T = float]':
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_IMU/IMU.h:18:8:   instantiated from here
../sketchbook/libraries/AP_Compass/../AP_Math/vector3.h:54:17: warning: operation on '((Vector3<float>*)this)->Vector3<float>::x' may be undefined
In file included from ../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Common.h:37:0,
                 from ../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/BetterStream.h:16,
                 from ../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/FastSerial.h:56,
                 from ../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/ArduPilotMega.pde:27:
../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Var.h: In constructor 'AP_VarT<T>::AP_VarT(AP_Var_group*, AP_Var::Key, T, const prog_char_t*, AP_Var::Flags) [with T = int, AP_Var::Key = unsigned int, AP_Var::Flags = unsigned char]':
../sketchbook/libraries/PID/PID.h:43:47:   instantiated from here
../sketchbook/libraries/FastSerial/../AP_Common/AP_Var.h:514:5: warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/climb_rate.pde:7:15: warning: shadowed declaration is here
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: In function 'int8_t dump_log(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:116:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/commands_logic.pde: In function 'bool verify_may()':
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/commands_logic.pde:201:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde: At global scope:
../sketchbook/ArduPilotMega/Log.pde:13:15: warning: 'int8_t print_log_menu(uint8_t, const Menu::arg*)' declared 'static' but never defined
make: *** [/tmp/ArduPilotMega.build/ArduPilotMega.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Which one between 1292 files? I can't understand from the error

Comment: [macro if statement returns error: operator '&&' has no right operand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48538243/608639)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue with recent versions of ArduPilot for certain build environments.

[Issue reported Jan 2, 2013](https://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/issues/detail?id=842)