# macro if statement returns error: operator '&&' has no right operand

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am compiling my code on many linux machines, on a specific machine, I receive the following error:

```
error: operator '&&' has no right operand
```

The macro code is:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49) && KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11
```

where LINUX_VERSION_CODE and KERNEL_VERSION are defined in linux sources and KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL is defined in my Makefile

```
KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL :=$(word 1, $(subst ., ,$(word 2, $(subst -, ,$(KERNEL_HEADERS)))))
```

If i change the code to 2 different lines, like this, **it works**:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49) 
#if KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11
  ...
#endif //KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11
#endif
```

Is it possible to still keep it with one #if ?
I use gcc version 4.9.0 (Debian 4.9.0-7)

The following macro does not work:

```
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49)) && (KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11)  

#if ((LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49)) && (KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11))  

#if defined(KERNEL_MAJOR) && defined(KERNEL_MINOR) && defined(KERNEL_MICRO) && defined(KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL) && defined(KERNEL_VERSION) && 
defined(LINUX_VERSION_CODE) && \
     (LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49)) && (KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11)
```

Comment: Try `#endif` instead of `#end`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that, i edited the code in the SO question, but the problem is still relevant

Comment: What do you mean you "dont want this"? It is necessary to have a corresponding #endif for every #if

Comment: @machine_1 I want only one if statement. why do I need 2 if statements instead of using && operator ?

Comment: If it works when in 2 separate lines, then I would try to put braces on each term in the original (one-line) expression.

Comment: Something like `#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49)) && (KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11)`.

Comment: @goodvibration I tried, does not work, Thats why i asked question, Also, I have included the gcc version, on my other gcc it works fine !! it is specific to this one !! thanks for trying :)

Comment: and what's the computed value of `KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL` ?  could you define it to 11 in your code ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre error: "KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL" redefined [-Werror]
 #define KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL 11

Comment: When you say that "it works" with two separate lines, is the nested `#if` being considered?

Comment: of course. Undefine it first with `#undef` for the test

Comment: @WeatherVane yes the nested if is considered

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ok, we are getting somewhere, If i #undef and #define KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL in my code (and not makefile) then it OK

Comment: can you just assign this value to a variable (int a = KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL) and see the outcome of -E output

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre We seem to find the problem, the command i execute to define KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL return null or empty on the specific kernel im running on, so if its null or empty, the #if defined macro on KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL returns true, During compilation output I see: DKERNEL_MICRO=21 -DKERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL="

Comment: defining it empty triggers the error in both cases. With && and without (already tried that :)). That doesn't explain why it works with 2 `#if`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are write, and I was wrong in my answer to WeatherVane , on this specific kernel I compile, Im not entering the nested if. Why it works with 2 if is because i currently compile on kernel 4.1.21.x86_64.1 and the first #if checks if kernel 3.12.49.. so the second #if macro is not executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it turns out that the error source is that `KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL` is defined in the makefile but empty.

In that case, the 2 lines aren't equivalent, since

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49) && KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11
```

evaluates both parts no matter what the the outcome of the first test is, so the preprocessor stumbles on the syntax error when meeting `&& == 11`.

But if `LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49)` is false, with this construct:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE == KERNEL_VERSION(3,12,49) 
#if KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11
  ...
#endif //KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL == 11
#endif
```

you're not entering the first `#if` so the inner `#if` (which is wrong since worth `#if == 11`) belongs to a block which skipped by the preprocessor, which explains that there's no error.

Note that if `KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL` is not defined, `#if` sees that as `0`, that wouldn't have triggered any error.

you can protect against ill-defined `KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL` with this (seen in [Test for empty macro definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102351/test-for-empty-macro-definition), I have added a better answer now)

```
#if (KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL + 0) == 0
#undef KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL
#define KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL 0
#endif
```

so if the macro is defined empty (or is 0), undefine it and define it to a `0` value. You could even detect (see my answer in the link above to understand how it works) if it's empty instead of `0` like this:

```
#if (0-KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL-1)==1 && (KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL+0)!=-2
#error "KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL defined empty"
#endif
```

Comment: What is the best practice for this problem ? to dummy define KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL in my makefile if empty ? since #if defined(KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL) does not do the job

Comment: KERNEL_PATCH_LEVEL is defined but "ill", I think i'd rather get compilation issues rather then defining it to dummy 0, that would hurt me later on some cases and would be hard to detect. Since it only fails in the 2nd if. on the problematic kernels that I will enter the first if, i rather fail then passing 0 (since kernel versions ends with 0).